# Has anyone attempted to place compiled code in an NSBundle and load it at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, ios, dynamic, uikit, nsbundle

If so, how did you do it? I've read up on the Mac documentation, but am not experienced at creating bundles in iOS. To be clear, the app is not going on the app store so I'm not concerned about app store guidelines or hidden APIs. I'm aware of loading non-compiled assets and resources from bundles, but would like to load executable, compiled code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is a `.a` library not just a collection of compiled code?

Comment: It is, but an NSBundle suits the purpose a bit better. The bundle will be downloaded via web service and will include non-compiled resources as well.

Comment: Had just written an answer to this about the Apple guidelines, but I've just read your question again and had to delete it!
Is your question asking how to create the bundle or how to download the bundle?

Comment: @James: it doesn't matter, you are not allowed bundles except the application bundle on iOS.

Comment: You are allowed bundles outside of the app store. The question is whether you can include compiled code in the bundle.

Comment: @JeremyP The question isn't a matter of what is permitted, just what is possible. The OP doesn't want to submit the app to the store.